# Flutter: Download PDF files from server fail

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-downloader

When to try to download PDF file (from our host), it start download, and the notification start to appear, but finally it fail to download.

**Here the log report show the error**

```
D/ColorViewRootUtil( 8717): nav bar mode ignore false downX 581 downY 1184
D/ColorViewRootUtil( 8717): nav bar mode ignore false downX 581 downY 1184 mScreenHeight 2280 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=581.0, y[0]=1184.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8621316, downTime=8621316, deviceId=1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]( 8717): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport( 8717): Create ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::connect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys( 8717): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x718dc93000,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x718dc93000)
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): DownloadWorker{url=https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf,filename=null,savedDir=/sdcard/download/,header={},isResume=false,status=ENQUEUED
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: RUNNING, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Open connection to https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Headers = {}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Type = application/pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Length = 138650
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Charset = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Disposition = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): fileName = d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
E/DownloadWorker( 8717): It looks like you are trying to save file in public storage but not setting 'saveInPublicStorage' to 'true'
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: FAILED, progress: -1}
W/System.err( 8717): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:393)
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err( 8717):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper( 8717): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=52f3d981-1c8c-4174-afe1-132b4a6f1134, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::disconnect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/View    ( 8717): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.FrameLayout{69c7301 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-376,125}
I/InputTransport( 8717): Destroy ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0D/ColorViewRootUtil( 8717): nav bar mode ignore false downX 581 downY 1184 mScreenHeight 2280 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=581.0, y[0]=1184.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8621316, downTime=8621316, deviceId=1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]( 8717): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport( 8717): Create ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::connect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys( 8717): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x718dc93000,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x718dc93000)
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): DownloadWorker{url=https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf,filename=null,savedDir=/sdcard/download/,header={},isResume=false,status=ENQUEUED
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: RUNNING, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Open connection to https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Headers = {}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Type = application/pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Length = 138650
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Charset = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Disposition = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): fileName = d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
E/DownloadWorker( 8717): It looks like you are trying to save file in public storage but not setting 'saveInPublicStorage' to 'true'
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: FAILED, progress: -1}
W/System.err( 8717): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:393)
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err( 8717):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper( 8717): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=52f3d981-1c8c-4174-afe1-132b4a6f1134, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::disconnect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/View    ( 8717): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.FrameLayout{69c7301 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-376,125}
I/InputTransport( 8717): Destroy ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0mScreenHeight 2280 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 0 rotation 0 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=581.0, y[0]=1184.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=8621316, downTime=8621316, deviceId=1, source=0x1002, displayId=0 }
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]( 8717): hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false
I/InputTransport( 8717): Create ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::connect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/mali_winsys( 8717): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x718dc93000,bufferCount=3)
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x718dc93000)
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): DownloadWorker{url=https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf,filename=null,savedDir=/sdcard/download/,header={},isResume=false,status=ENQUEUED
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: RUNNING, progress: 0}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Open connection to https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Headers = {}
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Type = application/pdf
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Length = 138650
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Charset = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Content-Disposition = null
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): fileName = d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf
E/DownloadWorker( 8717): It looks like you are trying to save file in public storage but not setting 'saveInPublicStorage' to 'true'
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
D/DownloadWorker( 8717): Update notification: {notificationId: 12, title: https://connect-elearning.com/newVersion/uploads/lesson_files/d19dbae4957c042e2e790522802a0abe.pdf, status: FAILED, progress: -1}
W/System.err( 8717): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:393)
W/System.err( 8717):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err( 8717):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err( 8717):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper( 8717): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=52f3d981-1c8c-4174-afe1-132b4a6f1134, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
D/Surface ( 8717): Surface::disconnect(this=0x718dc93000,api=1)
D/View    ( 8717): [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.FrameLayout{69c7301 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-376,125}
I/InputTransport( 8717): Destroy ARC handle: 0x7282b4a2e0
```

**And here part of DownloadWorker.kt file, that contain the error message shown in log error**

**It looks like you are trying to save file in public storage but not setting 'saveInPublicStorage' to 'true'**

```
private fun createFileInAppSpecificDir(filename: String, savedDir: String): File? {
        val newFile = File(savedDir, filename)
        try {
            val rs: Boolean = newFile.createNewFile()
            if (rs) {
                return newFile
            } else {
                logError("It looks like you are trying to save file in public storage but not setting 'saveInPublicStorage' to 'true'")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            logError("Create a file using java.io API failed ")
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: _This error is also happening on Android when the file is in the directory but I'm trying to download it using the downloader_ as mentioned https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/620

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_downloader/issues/611#issuecomment-1059124963) response. Seems you need to pass the option it is telling you to set, into the downloader. That, or the file you are trying to create has a bad path / name. Do all directories in the path leading to the file actually exist?

Comment: @OMiShah Here, It happen on Android & iOS